# IE7 Div creating table

Tags: html, css, asp.net, css-tables

Only in IE does this not work, it displays the cells stacked vertically on top one another? Is there anyway to fix this so that IE7 will display it like a table?

```
<div class="table" style="width: 1100px; margin-top: 5px;";>
    <div class="tr header">
    <div class="td" style="width: 2%"></div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 2%;"></div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 14%;">Name</div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 15%;">Company</div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 9%;">Type</div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 13%;">Phone</div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 21%;">Email</div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 17%;">City/State</div>
    <div class="td" style="width: 8%;">Region</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tr">
    <div class="td"><input type="image" name="Contacts1$rep$ctl01$imgdelbtn" id="Contacts1_rep_ctl01_imgdelbtn" src="images/del.png" style="border-width:0px;" /></div>
    <div class="td"><a href="EContact.aspx?id=25"><img alt="" src="images/edit.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px" /></a></div>
    <div class="td"><a href="Uss.aspx?id=25">Bob&nbsp;Smith</a></div>
    <div class="td"><a id="Contacts1_rep_ctl01_CompanyLnkBtn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('Contacts1$rep$ctl01$CompanyLnkBtn','')">Ops</a></div>
    <div class="td">User</div>
    <div class="td">555-555-5555</div>
    <div class="td"><a href='mailto:ops@ops.com'>ops@ops.com</a></div>
    <div class="td">Ops&nbsp;HI</div>
    <div class="td">Midwest</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tr" style="background-color: #F0F0F0">
    <div class="td"><input type="image" name="Contacts1$rep$ctl02$imgdelbtn" id="Contacts1_rep_ctl02_imgdelbtn" src="images/delete.png" style="border-width:0px;" /></div>
    <div class="td"><a href="E.aspx?id=78"><img alt="" src="images/edit.png" style="width: 16px; height: 16px" /></a></div>
    <div class="td"><a href="Uss.aspx?id=78">Bob&nbsp; Stevens</a></div>
    <div class="td"><a id="Contacts1_rep_ctl02_CompanyLnkBtn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('Contacts1$rep$ctl02$CompanyLnkBtn','')">ABC CO</a></div>
    <div class="td">User</div>
    <div class="td">000.000.0000</div>
    <div class="td"><a href='mailto:test@test.com'>test@test.com</a></div>
    <div class="td">OHHNO&nbsp;CA</div>
    <div class="td">Midwest</div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.table 
{
    border: 1px solid #808080; 
    display: table;
}
div.tr 
{
    border: 1px solid #808080; 
    display: table-row;
}
div.td 
{
    border: 1px solid #808080; 
    display: table-cell; 
    height: 25px; 
    padding-left: 5px; 
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle ;
}
div.header 
{
    background-color: #E0E0E0; 
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: That is tabular data. **Use a `table`.** It fixes IE7 and it fixes your code semantically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows and columns of logically-associated data belong in a **table**. DIVs are the wrong tool for the job.

While we've all be told not to use TABLEs, that only applies to using them for layouts. A grid is not a layout, it is a table.

Answer (score 1):

There really is no problem displaying tabular data in a table. That is the point of the table.
Don't feel that you need to display data in div tags.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply use table instead div?

If you look at [this table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html) you will see, that IE7 doesn not support "table". I suggest that you try to solve the problem with "[float](http://webdesign.about.com/od/advancedcss/a/aa010107.htm)".

Answer (score 0):

IE prior to IE8 doesn't support display: table*

Don't even try. It won't work.